# A short, easy riddle

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I hide until you find me.

You seek until you know me.

Once you know me, you will know me.

I am ___ ______.

Comment: While entertaining, this riddle is (arguably) wrong: (1) sometimes it's in plain sight; sometimes even before you know you want it; (2) some people give up looking; and (3) sometimes it takes years to determine that you've got a good one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The Answer

I hide until you find me.

> The answer to a question isn't immediately obvious

You seek until you know me.

> You try to find the answer to the question, until you've got it.

Once you know me, you will know me.

> Once you know the answer to the question, well, you know the answer!

Comment: Ahhh...nice one.

Comment: Yep.  Once I can officially declare this correct, I'm off to come up with something less embarrassingly easy.

Comment: I was about to put "the knowledge", in general form.

Answer (score 7):

**First attempt**

> The truth

I hide until you find me.

> it is hidden until if found (like everything else)

You seek until you know me.

> You want to know the truth

Once you know me, you will know me.

> Once you know the truth you cannon un-know it.

**Second attempt:**

> Knowledge

I hide until you find me.

> until we know something, it is hidden from us

You seek until you know me.

> We all seek knowledge

Once you know me, you will know me.

> once you have knowledge, you "know" it.

Comment: Really bloody good but there is a better fit mostly by virtue of the last line.

Comment: @BrentHackers. See my second atempt.

Comment: Also good.  KoA got the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

I am your

> soul mate.

<sup>Yeah, I know, it doesn't fit the lengths of the blanks.</sup>

I hide until you find me.

> [“Of all the gin joints, in all the towns, in all the world, …”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAS4o51tPzA)

You seek until you know me.

> Some people go to great lengths (including using the Internet!)
> to find a mate.

Once you know me, you will know me.

> The conventional wisdom is that, when you find true love, “you'll know it.”